# How to install the correct version and content of kerasNLP with pip？

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

My Environment

- OS: windows 10
- python version 3.12.2
- pip 24.0
- had never install tensorflow , keras or keras_nlp

I try to run following commands to install keras_nlp and keras following this [introduction](https://www.kaggle.com/models/google/gemma/frameworks/keras/variations/gemma_instruct_7b_en/?utm_source=agd&utm_medium=referral&utm_campaign=gemma-cta&utm_content=).

```
pip install -U keras-nlp
pip install -U keras
```

Command run successed.
But the kerasNLP I installed seems have incorrect content, [image: keras_nlp_init] which supposed to have many models over here.

Here is the demo which I want to test.

```
import keras_nlp
import os
os.environ["KERAS_BACKEND"] = "tensorflow"

gemma_lm = keras_nlp.models.GemmaCausalLM.from_preset("gemma_instruct_7b_en")
gotA = gemma_lm.generate("Keras is a", max_length=30)

print(gotA)

# Generate with batched prompts.
gotB = gemma_lm.generate(["Keras is a", "I want to say"], max_length=30)

print(gotB)
```

Program always shutdown with following log:

```
2024-02-25 23:23:39.045761: I tensorflow/core/util/port.cc:113] oneDNN custom operations are on. You may see slightly different numerical results due to floating-point round-off errors from different computation orders. To turn them off, set the environment variable `TF_ENABLE_ONEDNN_OPTS=0`.
2024-02-25 23:23:39.504814: I tensorflow/core/util/port.cc:113] oneDNN custom operations are on. You may see slightly different numerical results due to floating-point round-off errors from different computation orders. To turn them off, set the environment variable `TF_ENABLE_ONEDNN_OPTS=0`.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "d:\llm_demo\gemma.py", line 5, in <module>
    gemma_lm = keras_nlp.models.GemmaCausalLM.from_preset("gemma_instruct_7b_en")
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
AttributeError: module 'keras_nlp' has no attribute 'models'
```

If there any thing I can do to make this demo work?

Comment: KerasNLP is new and often makes breaking changes, so for the time being, I think it is better to reach out to keras-team via github ticket.

Comment: Got it, I'll try github ticket. tx